# Injecting dependency to Linq to Sql

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, dependency-injection

Is there a mechanism to inject dependencies into Linq to Sql or entity framework entities? If so would it be a sensible approach?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was not clear.
I want to be able to inject sevices eg. IEmailer into linq to sql entities using one of the many dependancy injection frameworks eg. windsor spring, unity etc.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you after? Note that you can use LINQ-to-SQL without the attributes, if you want to use existing classes... you need to use an [external xml file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386907.aspx) to hold the mappings, and an [`XmlMappingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.xmlmappingsource.aspx).

Note that this won't work with Entity Framework; only LINQ-to-SQL.